# Traveling from Anaklia Georgia to Greece?

Tags: international-travel, georgia-country, italy, greece, black-sea

I will be in Anaklia Georgia from May 25- July 8 and Wanted to look into traveling to Greece at the end and then Italy from Greece (If possible it would be nice to squeeze egypt in there also). I am from the U.S. and really have no idea where to start even looking into transportation in Europe.  We obviously are looking for the cheapest options available. Can anyone help me or direct me to a website that might have some information on the topic?

Thanks in advance for any help!! :)

Comment: Hi Jesse.  Welcome to Travel.SE! Firstly, we try to ask questions on here that can be answered objectively, and you're fine there (see the [faq]).  However, we also try to be precise and not ask anything too open-ended or that might cause discussion, rather than answers.  Currently you're asking about a huge topic - transportation in Europe (although you've mentioned two countries).  It's quite big - if you could edit your question to be a bit more detailed in what you're after - history, prices, types of transport, train, bus, plane - anything you think might help, it'd help the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Get a Lonely Planet. Or a few digital chapters from their online store. Probably the best place to start. Wikitravel is a good resource, but lacking on more obscure destinations.

Unless you have boatloads of time and assuming you're traveling overland, skip Egypt. There's no easy way to get there from the northern Mediterranean, unless you fly.

Buses in Turkey are very affordable and good. So are trains, but their network is limited. You can assume that it will be easy to find buses from larger cities to larger cities in Turkey once you get there.

Trains in Greece ain't half bad and affordable. The ferry from Greece to Italy can be pricey, so compare your options. For ferries, try ferrylines.com.
Slower trains in Italy are well priced.

Budget airlines serve several cities in Turkey from central and south eastern Europe. Check hipmunk.com and AirNinja.com to look for cheap flights and budget airlines respectively.

Use hotelscombined.com, bookhostels.com and airbnb.com to find affordable accommodation.

For international train travel, start at seat61.com.

Comment: Actually the Lonely Planet for Georgia, Armenia, and Azerbaijan is pretty poor by their usual standards. Anaklia is not in there at all. I believe a new edition will soon be out but I would be surprised if Anaklia is in it either. They're building a resort there but I just came from there and it's not ready for anyone other people who like to see quirky places nobody goes to (-:

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you'll update the question, but one site that definitely helps find ways to get around is [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/).  I found it invaluable the last few years for all types of countries, and transport.

For example, you could look at a particular country, or even look at something like [Rail Travel in Europe](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rail_travel_in_Europe).

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Flying from Georgia towards Greece

Close to Anaklia (154km according to Google Maps) you can find the Batumi International Airport. With a quick search I found a flight to Istanbul with 92 euros per person (tax included) close to the dates you gave.

### 2. From Istanbul to Greece

It depends which parts of Greece you want to visit. Regarding trains the wikipedia article of the Hellenic Railways Organisation is extensive. There are bus services to Thessaloniki and Athens from Istanbul as well (i.e. http://www.crazy-holidays.gr/08519BE0.en.aspx)

### 3. From Greece to Italy

I suggest ferries.gr to search for tickets. Alternatively Ryanair is connecting these two countries (for example from Volos, which is located centrally in Greece to Milan).

Have a nice time!

Comment: Even though Anaklia is close to Batumi as the crow flies, it isn't so close as the car drives because there is a national park between the two without a road going through. I'm in Batumi now and was in Anaklia less than a week ago. You would have to go up to Zugdidi, which surely has an airport, then back down the other way to Batumi. It's actually still not far since Georgia is a small country, and Batumi surely has a much better connected airport than Zugdidi does.

Comment: When I was last in Greece just over six months ago all international trains had been stopped as part of the austerity measures. National trains were still running and international buses were running. It would be best to check if international rail service has been reinstated.